# How to call windows folder dialog in a localhost php program

Tags: windows, dialog, directory

Is this possible? I have a process where I wish to read all files in a selected folder. Or is this something I cannot even do on a localhost?

Comment: The [input element](https://jsfiddle.net/ygb8geyd/) has a "file" type which, when pressed, will launch a folder browser dialog. Add the multiple attribute for multiple files

Answer (score 0):

*PHP* will be able to process the form you sent.

To get file from your *PC* you will need a html `<form>` with an `<input>` that as the attribute for data or file.

And your form will post the file to *PHP* where you can read it. Remember that *PHP* run's on the server side.

You could use *JavaScript* as well since the file is on client side. Depends on your needs.

So yes it is possible. Instead of dealing with one file you will deal with an array of files.

It is possible with *PHP* to read the content of a folder but it will always be the content of the server file system never the client's.

Maybe you can start here
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.readdir.php

Comment: Yes, I'm using form input file. And like was stated above, have used multiple. I just didn't want to manually select all files. Prefer to get the folder path and use glob to grab the files.